# Unable to load NuGet dll with platform specific dlls in netcoreapp

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard

I am unable to load `System.Data.Client` dll from it's nuget package using the ICompilationAssemblyResolver I have available in a netcoreapp. The bulk of the Assembly resolving is borrowed from [here](https://samcragg.wordpress.com/2017/06/30/resolving-assemblies-in-net-core/), and works great for the most part. It looks like so:

```
internal sealed class AssemblyResolver : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ICompilationAssemblyResolver assemblyResolver;
    private readonly DependencyContext dependencyContext;
    private readonly AssemblyLoadContext loadContext;

    public AssemblyResolver(string path)
    {
        this.Assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
        this.dependencyContext = DependencyContext.Load(this.Assembly);

        this.assemblyResolver = new CompositeCompilationAssemblyResolver(new ICompilationAssemblyResolver[]
        {
            new AppBaseCompilationAssemblyResolver(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)),
            new ReferenceAssemblyPathResolver(),
            new PackageCompilationAssemblyResolver()
        });

        this.loadContext = AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(this.Assembly);
        this.loadContext.Resolving += OnResolving;
    }

    public Assembly Assembly { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.loadContext.Resolving -= this.OnResolving;
    }

    private Assembly OnResolving(AssemblyLoadContext context, AssemblyName name)
    {
        bool NamesMatch(RuntimeLibrary runtime)
        {
            return string.Equals(runtime.Name, name.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        RuntimeLibrary library =
        this.dependencyContext.RuntimeLibraries.FirstOrDefault(NamesMatch);
        if (library != null)
        {
            var wrapper = new CompilationLibrary(
                library.Type,
                library.Name,
                library.Version,
                library.Hash,
                library.RuntimeAssemblyGroups.SelectMany(g => g.AssetPaths),
                library.Dependencies,
                library.Serviceable);

            var assemblies = new List<string>();
            this.assemblyResolver.TryResolveAssemblyPaths(wrapper, assemblies);
            if (assemblies.Count > 0)
            {
                return this.loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblies[0]);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

However I am unable to load a dll that references `System.Data.Client` @ `4.3.1` as at runtime I get the error message:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.IO.FileNotFoundException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' 
occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll: 'Could not load file or 
assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I am not sure why it is trying to load 4.1.0 when I have specified 4.3.0 but I think that is a bit of a red herring. I suspect that the  `PackageCompilationAssemblyResolver` only looks under the `lib` folder, and the package in question does not have one for netstandard. It does however have one for specific runtimes:

[image: Contents of System.Data.SqlClient]

Armed with this information I have created an incredibly crude AssemblyLoader that looks under the runtimes folder for a nuget package and I am able to load the dll and run my program as I expect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution;

namespace Loader
{
    public class CrudeCompilationAssemblyResolver : ICompilationAssemblyResolver
    {
        private readonly string[] _nugetPackageDirectories;

        public CrudeCompilationAssemblyResolver()
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME");
            var defaultPath = Path.Combine(basePath, ".nuget", "packages");
            _nugetPackageDirectories = new [] { defaultPath };
        }

        public bool TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List<string> assemblies)
        {
            if (_nugetPackageDirectories == null || _nugetPackageDirectories.Length == 0 || !string.Equals(library.Type, "package", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach (var directory in _nugetPackageDirectories)
            {
                string packagePath;

                var fullPath = Path.Combine(directory, library.Name, library.Version, "runtimes", "unix", "lib", "netstandard1.3", $"{library.Name}.dll");
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    assemblies.AddRange(new[] { fullPath });
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;        
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there a better/officially sanctioned way of loading this troublesome assembly from a nuget package? Or do I need to make my crude loader a lot less crude?

Full repo is here: [CustomAssemblyResolver](https://github.com/Meberem/CustomAssemblyResolver)

Comment: 1. Why are you trying to manually load it? For projects, NuGet will generate an assets file (input to deps.json generation) containing resolved paths.
2. Compilation assembly resolvers aren't meant to yield assemblies that can be loaded, only compiled against them (=> compiler input like reference assemblies, not actual implementations).

Comment: I would rather not load it manually, I had kind of assumed that the DependencyResolver would handle all of that for me. I had seen the `obj/project.assets.json` which I assume is used in producing the `deps.json` but I am not sure how to use it.

I did wonder about using CompilationAssemblyResolvers. I was initially using the `RuntimeAssemblyGroups` property on the `RuntimeLibrary` from the dependency resolver but the one for `System.Data.SqlClient` had nothing, so I went looking for other solutions and stumbled across the first link.